# How to add module into content in joomla 3.1

Tags: php, html, joomla

Let's say i have such html/php structure of index.php in my template:

```
<div class="content">
      <jdoc:include type="component" />
      <div class="price_request">
        <div class="right_area">
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="price_request" />
        </div>
      </div>    
      <div class="feedback">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="feedback" />
      </div>   
    </div>
```

how can i do, that my price_request module is in text of content.

if it would be easier, i display it on image:

[image]

orange is my content, and green is module.

how can i do this?

Comment: Did you check this - http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F

Comment: @Irfan it's for every article, but i need to do for all

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic templating question. You can find extensive documentation on how to do this. Here you get a good quick start: http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template

Basically you need to create a module position whereever you want to display module content. You already have two of those in your example, such as <*jdoc:include type="modules" name="price_request" /*>. 
The position called "price_request" is defined in your template xml file. Then you create your module (or go into the options of an existing one), and select the position of that name.

Mostly you will start with a template that already has lots of positions. Then you might prefer to move an existing position within index.php of the template, and/or tweak the position with CSS.
(Some special templates use other files than index.php, but rarely.)
Anyway, the point is, the module output goes wherever the <*jdoc:include type="modules" name="name_of_your_module_position" /*> is.

But then, if that isn't enough for you, try something like http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modulesanywhere

Comment: hm, you write me how to put in module some content like plugin, but how can i in my content (or article material put this "partial")?

Comment: What do you mean by "partial"? For the resulting code, i.e. what arrives at the browser, there's no difference between plugin and module. The greatest difference is that plugins are usually added into the text of an article, while module positions are added into the template file (index.php). And then modules are assigned to these positions.
Only with the mentioned extension, you can really add modules into articles like plugins.
(Normally modules do not belong into articles, that's what plugins are for. But if you don't have the plugin you need, the modulesanywhere extension is a workaround.)